# How to make elements hidden within UIView, when resized smaller than element

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I am trying to make it so when i adjust the frame of my UiView, all the elements inside such as labels boxes etc are hidden.

I attacked my .xib file to the uiview like so.

```
LogInViewController *logIn = [[LogInViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"LogInViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.loginView addSubview:logIn.view];
```

Then when buttons are pressed. The logInView frame will animate to smaller - thus wanting the elements to also be hidden to give this tab view effect :)

[image]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Thanks for your help :) Im still quite new so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `clipsToBounds:`?

```
[[self view] setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

This will mask everything that is outside of the view's frame so it is no longer visible.